# clear the cache of div after reload the same url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp

create a model window in html page load some payment information like order number, amount and submit button from server. If modal window exit or reload the modal window means, already loaded jsp content (order no, amount) was showed in the body.Generate new order number can take some times, after generated it'll shown. How to clear the already loaded jsp content in the div?

#### .html

```
   <div ng-model="paymentmodel" ng-include="paymenturl"></div>
```

#### .js

```
    $scope.paymenturl=$scope.urlsetting+'iwa/PaymentForm.jsp?orderNo='+$scope.orderNo+'&amount='+$scope.amount+'&IOMS='+$scope.selectedIOMS.connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but you can try sommething like this

```
 function randomNumber(){
            return Math.random() *10000;
 }
 $scope.paymenturl=$scope.urlsetting+'iwa/PaymentForm.jsp?orderNo='+$scope.orderNo+'&amount='+$scope.amount+'&IOMS='+$scope.selectedIOMS.connection+'&rnd='randomNumber
```

Now you always give an other url and the browser won't look to the cache